# Why does nvidia-smi return "GPU access blocked by the operating system" in WSL2 under Windows 10 21H2

Tags: cuda, gpu, wsl-2

### Installing CUDA on WSL2

I've installed Windows 10 21H2 on both my desktop (AMD 5950X system with RTX3080) and my laptop (Dell XPS 9560 with i7-7700HQ and GTX1050) following the instructions on https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html:

1. Install CUDA-capable driver in Windows
2. Update WSL2 kernel in PowerShell: `wsl --update`
3. Install CUDA toolkit in Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2
   (Note that you don't install a CUDA driver in WSL2, the instructions explicitly tell that the CUDA driver should not be installed.):

```
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
$ sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.4.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local/7fa2af80.pub
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

### The Error

On my desktop `nvidia-smi` and CUDA samples are working fine in WSL2.
But on my laptop running `nvidia-smi` in WSL2 returns:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
Failed to properly shut down NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
```

I'm aware my laptop has NVIDIA Optimus with both Intel IGP and NVIDIA GTX1050, but CUDA is working fine in Windows. Only not in WSL2.
But I also could not find any information that CUDA is not supposed to work in WSL2 for Optimus systems.

### What I've tried

I've tried the following mitigations, but the error remains:

- reinstalling the Windows CUDA driver again and rebooting
- Making the GTX1050 the preferred GPU in global settings in the NVIDIA control panel
- Making the GTX1050 the default physx processor
- Following the same steps for a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL2

### The question

Is this a CUDA WSL2 bug? Or does CUDA simply not work with Optimus? Or how can I fix or further debug this?

### More details

I've compared running `nvidia-smi.exe` in Windows powershell between my desktop and laptop, and they both return the same software versions:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nvidia-smi
Wed Nov 17 21:46:50 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.06       Driver Version: 510.06       CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     75MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Even more details

The full `nvidia-smi.exe -q` on my laptop in Windows Powershell returns the following information about my laptop's GPU:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nvidia-smi -q

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Wed Nov 17 21:48:19 2021
Driver Version                            : 510.06
CUDA Version                              : 11.6

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Product Name                          : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Product Brand                         : GeForce
    Product Architecture                  : Pascal
    Display Mode                          : Disabled
    Display Active                        : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                      : N/A
    MIG Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
    Driver Model
        Current                           : WDDM
        Pending                           : WDDM
    Serial Number                         : N/A
    GPU UUID                              : GPU-7645072f-7516-5488-316d-6277d101f64e
    Minor Number                          : N/A
    VBIOS Version                         : 86.07.3e.00.1c
    MultiGPU Board                        : No
    Board ID                              : 0x100
    GPU Part Number                       : N/A
    Module ID                             : 0
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : N/A
        OEM Object                        : N/A
        ECC Object                        : N/A
        Power Management Object           : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    GSP Firmware Version                  : N/A
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization Mode               : None
        Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
    IBMNPU
        Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                               : 0x01
        Device                            : 0x00
        Domain                            : 0x0000
        Device Id                         : 0x1C8D10DE
        Bus Id                            : 00000000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id                     : 0x07BE1028
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                       : 3
                Current                   : 3
            Link Width
                Max                       : 16x
                Current                   : 16x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                          : N/A
            Firmware                      : N/A
        Replays Since Reset               : 0
        Replay Number Rollovers           : 0
        Tx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
        Rx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
    Fan Speed                             : N/A
    Performance State                     : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                              : Active
        Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active
        SW Power Cap                      : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                       : Not Active
            HW Thermal Slowdown           : Not Active
            HW Power Brake Slowdown       : Not Active
        Sync Boost                        : Not Active
        SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active
        Display Clock Setting             : Not Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                             : 4096 MiB
        Used                              : 75 MiB
        Free                              : 4021 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                             : 256 MiB
        Used                              : 2 MiB
        Free                              : 254 MiB
    Compute Mode                          : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                               : 0 %
        Memory                            : 0 %
        Encoder                           : 0 %
        Decoder                           : 0 %
    Encoder Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    FBC Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    Ecc Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Double Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A
    Remapped Rows                         : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp                  : 40 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 102 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 97 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp            : 78 C
        GPU Target Temperature            : N/A
        Memory Current Temp               : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : N/A
        Power Draw                        : N/A
        Power Limit                       : N/A
        Default Power Limit               : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit              : N/A
        Min Power Limit                   : N/A
        Max Power Limit                   : N/A
    Clocks
        Graphics                          : 0 MHz
        SM                                : 0 MHz
        Memory                            : 405 MHz
        Video                             : 0 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                          : 1911 MHz
        SM                                : 1911 MHz
        Memory                            : 3504 MHz
        Video                             : 1708 MHz
    Max Customer Boost Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                        : N/A
        Auto Boost Default                : N/A
    Voltage
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Processes                             : None
```

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @eglease Thanks for the suggestion, I am rather new and I didn't think about other SE sites. However, when I search for 'cuda wsl2' then I'm getting quite a bit more related questions on stackoverflow.com vs superuser.com (39 vs 7).

Comment: SO is more about programming (writing code).  I see that most `cuda` questions on SO are either about programming or are closed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out that Windows 10 Update Assistant incorrectly reported it upgraded my OS to 21H2 on my laptop.
Checking Windows version by running `winver` reports that my OS is still 21H1.
Of course CUDA in WSL2 will not work in Windows 10 without 21H2.

After successfully installing 21H2 I can confirm CUDA works with WSL2 even for laptops with Optimus NVIDIA cards.

Comment: thank you, this helped me solve my issue. somehow I thought I had the latest Windows 10, but apparently not...

Comment: Also I am pretty sure you are NOT supposed to install anything cuda/gpu related IN wsl like you show in your post -- after you have the right version of Windows 10 or 11 you need to wsl --update though (see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html) You install drivers in Windows, but "Note: This is the only driver you need to install. Do not install any Linux display driver in WSL."

Comment: @Luther If you look closely in my post then you'll see that you indeed do not install the driver. It installs a special cuda-wsl package without the driver. Since you do of course need the CUDA toolkit & libraries to actually run CUDA programs.

Comment: So the key is to install win 10 21H`2`?

Comment: Certainly, but also to check the 21H2 install was successful. You might think with the updatetool finished it was successful, but that might not be the case.